# Effective ways of dealing with static analyser warnings caused by incidental use of reflection

Tags: static-analysis, reflection

I don't normally use reflection directly while programming in Java. But I do use APIs and frameworks that internally rely on reflection or annotations to provide customization points.

A lot of frameworks use annotations to set up dependency injection or do some sort of automated logic wiring on your behalf.

This results in a lot of field, method, and constructor accesses which the static code analyzer can't follow, resulting in many false positives (not only "unused method/field" warnings).
**Is my only realistic option to continue to suppress these warnings, or are there other things I can do to help the analyzer better understand the real entry points of my classes?**

I've heard some people discuss using test code for this purpose.

In a lot of the cases, I **could** probably write relevant test cases that make the warnings disappear, but I am worried about the rather large number of cases where that would involve testing implementation details instead of observable behavior. This code already has adequate branch coverage, and I don't want to write tests that I will regret writing every time I do maintenance. But if whitebox testing is really sometimes the "best" alternative, **are there ways to help minimize the downsides?** Fragility and implementation leakage are my primary concerns.

Comment: Code analyzers have warning suppression mechanisms precisely for this reason.

Comment: You'd have to ask about a specific analyzer, since they all differ. And that would then go to SO, since it's about a specific tool. But a lot of them allow either: Suppressing warnings on fields/methods that have X annotation, or allowing to suppress a rule entirely, and rewriting it to take your annotations into account. How exactly those are done and which is available depends on your tool.

Comment: @Ordous I know how to suppress the warnings in many different ways. I don't need help with that. I am specifically asking if I have alternatives to that, given that it does have significant downsides. If the answer is no, then so be it.

Comment: @TimSeguine What downsides would those be? You'd essentially have the tool better fit the reality of your code.

Comment: What are the downsides?  What does "fragility and implementation leakage" mean?

Comment: @TimSeguine If you suppress a warning across the board, you lose some of the value of the analyzer.  But if your tool allows you to suppress a specific error at specific location, it shouldn't be an issue.  The `SuppressWarnings` annotation can be used for this with Sonar, for example.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Quoting from the wikipedia article on whitebox testing "The resulting test can be fragile because they are tightly coupled to the specific implementation of the thing being tested. The code under test could be rewritten to implement the same functionality in a different way that invalidates the assumptions baked into the test. This could result in tests that fail unnecessarily or, in the worst case, tests that now give false positives and mask errors in the code." That is what I mean when I say fragility

Comment: @RobertHarvey And when I say implementation leakage, quite a few of these methods would have to have their visibility be changed in order to test them, or they would have to have partitions which expose extra test surfaces to be directly testable. This causes abstraction leakage. This is bad because of Hyrum's law: Given enough users eventually someone will rely on any observable behavior of a system. This is bad because of fragility.

Comment: I don't dispute that, but what does it have to do with code analyzers or their warnings?  In other news, I think I'm going to have to come up with some Laws of my own so that I can be quoted on the Internet.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I listed the advice I already heard for dealing with the problem I was having(i.e. testing). I brought that up because that advice doesn't seem to help me for the reason that it would in my case involve a lot of whitebox testing, which I am disinclined to do for the reasons I listed. Stack Exchange sites are really weird. If I didn't attempt to explain my reasoning, someone would have jumped on me for that too.

Comment: A fair point.  But I'm still not sure why you resist using the suppression mechanisms for their intended purpose.  Realistically, you have two options: suppress the warnings or live with them.  Which would be better for your purposes?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Both seem equally bad for different reasons. Usually I have found that when I think I only have two bad options, talking to others helps me find a much better third option. Apparently this seems like a situation where nobody has something clever that I missed though. Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use dynamic features (reflection, downcasts, metaprogramming, code generation, scripting languages) there's an implicit understanding that you are willingly sacrificing static analyzability for coding convenience. There is definitively a tradeoff here.

For many projects, this is not a good trade. Or maybe it was a good idea early in the inception of the project, but has now become a maintenance burden. When type checking, IDE support, and static analysis are more valuable than convenience, it may be worth rewriting the relevant parts to avoid dynamic features.

This is not always possible or desirable. Some problems are inherently dynamic. For some projects, writing extra boilerplate would be a larger maintenance burden than dealing with incomplete tool support. In your case, continuing to disable some static analysis checks may be the best you can do.

While the choice between expressiveness and static analysis is generally exclusive, there might be a third option: improve your tools. In the case of Java, you could perhaps write annotations that your static analysis tools understand.